# cross-env: command not found on Windows OS

Tags: node.js

I run `npm install` on my Mac, and command `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node build/dev-server.js` successes. Then I copy the whole project to my Windows computer, but the command `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node build/dev-server.js` failes, telling me `cross-env: command not found`. Is it due to different OS? Because I can't connect npm registry on my Windows OS. What can I do then?

Comment: `cross-env` needs to be a dependency of your project, and you should run `npm install` on Windows to get it installed.

Comment: So in different OS `npm install` will do different things, right?

Comment: No, but it will install dependencies that may not be yet installed on the other OS. Although perhaps you installed `cross-env` globally on your Mac, in which case you may want to do the same on Windows: `npm i -g cross-env`

Comment: Just because npm connection isn't available on Windows, which annoys me. I have just found the reason: `cross-env.cmd` lost under the `.bin` directory.